# Smack's XMPP over TCP connection stops after the main() method returns

Tags: java, smack

I started using the Ignite Smack API 4.1.6 for creating a basic XMPP over TCP client. I use the smack-tcp and smack-java7 API. The code is pretty basic.

```
//In a main

//Create XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration
//Create XMPPTCPConnection using the configuration
//connect and login
```

After logged in successfully and sent the first presence message, it seems that at the time the code into the main finishes executing the connection is shut down.

I expected that the API would created a TCP socket connection that stays alive into a separate thread, but it seems that it's not the behaviour I get.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM will exists if the `main()` method exists and if there a only daemon treads left. Smack uses daemon threads exclusively. Thus your JVM exists.

See also [if main method completes the execution, what happens to any long running thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426429/if-main-method-completes-the-execution-what-happens-to-any-long-running-thread)